# Move Lotus Notes data, formulas and macros to Excel Mac

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, vba

I have used Lotus 1-2-3 long time ago and Lotus Notes like 10 years ago.

I have a task I need to do. I need to move Lotus notes data, formulas and macros in Excel in MAC.

I remember long time ago I have done manually the following to move the data:

- From Lotus Notes, I exported and save it in the format "Tabular Text" (fixed width). Opened it in Excel and run the "Text to column".
- From Lotus Notes, I create a CSV file, which can be opened in Excel.

I remember the older version of Excel has an option to import Lotus 1-2-3. I also remember before in Excel VBA, in references you can use a Notes DLL to write a code to use Lotus Notes but now in the newer version of Excel I do not see any Notes DLL in the references.

Is there a way to automate from Lotus Notes to export the data, formulas and macros in Excel OR Is there a way in Excel VBA to automate to import the data, formulas and macros in Lotus Notes to Excel?

Any input or suggestions is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You might take a look at (http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-export-Lotus-Notes-views-to-a-Microsoft-Excel-database) for some help getting you started.

Comment: If the Notes client is properly installed, you should see both the Lotus Notes COM (rooted at lotus.NotesSession) and OLE (notes.NotesUIWorkspace and notes.Notessession) classes available in VBA. Not sure about that, though, if you have 64-bit Excel. The Notes client and the DLLs for the classes are only available in 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data from Notes into Excel, but not formulas or scripts.

You can access Notes from VBA in Excel, as Richard said, if your Notes client is properly installed you should see the COM object, and you can now access Domino data using VBA. This is of course Windows only.
You could also do the same using Java.

You can write an agent (or have someone do it for you) that will export your Notes data into a CSV file.
Here are two articles I wrote about this on my blog:
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-from-notes-to-excel-3-different-ways/
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

You could also write a REST API on your Domino server, exposing the data you want to export. Then you call it from Excel using VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I would go down the path of using the inbuilt domino dxl (NotesDXLExporter) which is an XML interpretation of the database you want to export as this means you don't need to understand a lot about Lotus Script or Java to get process running.

This should give you the agent/script names and possibly the code as well however I haven't played with this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

For moving data to Excel my favorite is POI: http://poi.apache.org/
Its a library that allows reading and writing Excel workbook with Java. This could quite easily be done with a Domino agent (You may need to increase JavaMaxHeapSize)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is get data from Lotus Notes Documents, right?

If that is the point, you need a developer to manipulate the documents with lotusscript and send the documents to Excel.